# Calculate distance in miles between two zip codes in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distance

Say I have two zip codes in one row in a table. Is there a way to calculate the distance between the two zip codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tabel` AS (
  SELECT '91356' home, '90045' work
)
SELECT home, work,
  ST_DISTANCE(home_geo, work_geo) / 1609.34 AS distance,
  home_geo, work_geo,
  ST_MAKELINE(ST_CLOSESTPOINT(home_geo, work_geo), ST_CLOSESTPOINT(work_geo, home_geo)) line
FROM (
  SELECT home, work,
    (
    SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(zipcode_geom) 
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area`
    WHERE zipcode = home
    ) home_geo,
     (
    SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(zipcode_geom) 
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area`
    WHERE zipcode = work
    ) work_geo
  FROM `project.dataset.tabel`
)
```

with output

```
home    work    distance            ...
91356   90045   12.794149725735204  ...
```

[image]

Above result would be visualized as below showing both zips and line representing shortest line in between them

[image]

Note: obviously, this is not a driving distance but rather shortest distance on the map - see more details on [ST_DISTANCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance)

Comment: one improvement: there is now a public table with Geography type, if you use it you don't pay the cost of ST_GeogFromText in the query:  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  zip1.zipcode zipcode1,
  zip2.zipcode zipcode2,
  ST_DISTANCE(zip1.geog, zip2.geog) distance
FROM
  `fh-bigquery.gis.zipcodes` zip1,
  `fh-bigquery.gis.zipcodes` zip2
WHERE
  zip1.zipcode != zip2.zipcode;
```

Comment: I would use official table -  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.zip_codes`